# SpriteKit: node Y position and touch Y position not consistent

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Totally new to SpriteKit, and iOS development in general.  I'm following a very basic SpriteKit tutorial, and noticed that a **node's** Y position isn't the same as a **touch's** Y position, when touched in the same spot as the node.  For example:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

  override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    // add a text label at X: 100 and Y: 100
    let labelNode = SKLabelNode(text: "X:100 Y:100")
    labelNode.position.x = 100
    labelNode.position.y = 100
    labelNode.fontSize = 20.0
    addChild(labelNode)
  }

  override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    // for each touch, print the X and Y positions
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
      println("You touched at X: \(touch.locationInView(self.view!).x) and Y: \(touch.locationInView(self.view!).y)")
    }
  }

}
```

This adds text at X:100 and Y:100, which is the bottom left of the scene (using the default `scene.anchorPoint`). And when you touch, it prints the X and Y of where you touched.

The weird thing is, **when I touch the center of the label node**, the X position of 1.) the node and 2.) where I touched are consistent.  But the Y's are not.  The node's Y is 100, but the touch's Y is 266.  See screenshot below:

[image: screenshot]

Can someone explain why this is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the culprit here is `locationInView()`, which returns a location in the coordinates space of the underlying view, which uses a different coordinate system as your scene/nodes. Using `locationInNode()` should sort this out.

From [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITouch_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITouch/locationInNode:):

> Returns the current location of the receiver in the coordinate system of the given node.

Use as follows:

```
println("You touched at X: \(touch.locationInNode(self).x) and Y: \(touch.locationInNode(self).y)")
```

Comment: Thanks! As a follow-up question: in `touch.locationInNode(self).x`, which class is `self` referring to?

Comment: The docs say it expects an instance of `SKNode`. How is `self` an `SKNode`?

Comment: @imderek Sure thing. In this case `self` is referring to your scene (instance of `SKScene`), which is a subclass of `SKEffectNode`, which is a subclass of `SKNode`.